# BSD getaddrinfo() endianness

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to familiarize myself with the networking BSD API. I understand the fact that multi bytes data submitted to the BSD API (like address and port) must be in network byte order and that we should use converting functions like htons() and htonl() to do this. This snippet of code shows that:

```
#define IP_ADDRESS(a, b, c, d)   ((((uint32_t)a) << 24) | (((uint32_t)b) << 16) | (((uint32_t)c) << 8) | ((uint32_t)d))

/* Set server port in BSD format */
memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IP_ADDRESS(192,168,1,1));
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(21);

/* Connect to server */
status = connect(H->bsdSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
```

Now I am trying to make use of getaddrinfo() in order to retrieve the address information from a server name. I tried that following code:

```
memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

getaddrinfo( "srvdc01", "21", &hints, &addr_list );

if (addr_list != NULL)
{
    ctx->fd = (int) socket( addr_list->ai_family, addr_list->ai_socktype,
                        addr_list->ai_protocol );
    if (ctx->fd >= 0)
        status = connect( ctx->fd, addr_list->ai_addr, addr_list->ai_addrlen );
}
```

I would have expected that the address returned by getaddrinfo() would be in network byte order in such a way it could be fed directly to the connect() function. Unfortunately, this does not work with the library I am using as the resulting connect is reverting the address bytes (I use Wireshark to investigate this issue).

Is it allowed to safely use addresses returned by getaddrinfo() for feeding the socket() and connect() calls?

Thanks, Franck

=== Update ===

Thanks guys for your comments. I could clarify things a little more. I ran the following code snippet with the following results:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *addr_list, *cur;
struct sockaddr_in addr_in;

memset(&addr_in, 0, sizeof(addr_in));
addr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr_in.sin_port = htons(21);
addr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0xC0A80101UL);  // 192.168.1.1
myprintf("%08x\n", addr_in.sin_addr.s_addr);

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

if( getaddrinfo( "srvdc01", "21", &hints, &addr_list ) == 0 )
{
    for( cur = addr_list; cur != NULL; cur = cur->ai_next )
    {
        ctx->fd = (int) socket( cur->ai_family, cur->ai_socktype,
                            cur->ai_protocol );
        if( ctx->fd >= 0 )
        {
            myprintf("%08x\n", ((struct sockaddr_in *)cur->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr);
        }
    }
}

freeaddrinfo( addr_list );
```

The first printf output (after htonl) gives c0a80101 while the second one (after socket creation) gives 0101a8c0. This was surprising because on my little endian platform, I would have expected the htonl() call to swap bytes to bring them in network byte order.

After reviewing documentation of our embedded networking library (third party commercial library), we could find that the BSD API they provide is actually a (quite) limited wrapper on top of their vendor specific network library API. There is a small notice about the fact that their library always work with the native system endianness so their htonl() function is always a dummy call that does nothing.

Now, looking at the link provided by Martin R. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freeaddrinfo.html, I agree with him that getaddrinfo() should return an address information suitable for a call to connect() which is visibly not the case with this embedded library.

Comment: What is IP_ADDRESS?

Comment: I am fairly sure that getaddrinfo fills the ai_addr entries in network byte order, so that they can directly be used with socket()  and connect().

Comment: But you should try *all* returned addresses, see e.g. http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getaddrinfoman.html for example code.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I edited the question to add the macro definition.

Comment: @MartinR Yes of course, this is only a simplified code to show my issue. But looking at your link (though it is not official documentation), it looks like the returned address is being used directly with socket() and connect() as you pointed out...

Comment: Um, how does that macro work?

Comment: I guess you need some `,`s there...

Comment: @FranckD.: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/freeaddrinfo.html says: *"Upon successful return of getaddrinfo(), the location to which res points shall refer to a linked list of addrinfo structures, each of which shall specify a **socket address and information for use in creating a socket** with which to use that socket address."* – In my understanding (and practical experience) the socket address structures are filled in **network byte order.**

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am not sure I understand your question... the macro simply packs the IP address on a 4-byte word in the host natural endianness

Comment: Why do you think `getaddrinfo` is returning the address in the host byte order?  What is the output of `printf("%08x", addr_list->ai_addr);`?

Comment: @dbush it is `struct sockaddr_t *`...

Comment: If you have `AF_UNSPEC` then you can get *any* address family first.

Comment: The debug print should be `printf("%08x\n", ((struct sockaddr_in *)addr_list->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr);` for ipv4.

Comment: OP please provide a proper [mcve]. A contained program that everyone can run.

Comment: We cannot verify how you investigated the issue in Wireshark. Why don't you add the print statement that Antti suggested above and show the output?

Comment: The macro requires (a,b,c,d) but you pass (a.b.c.d).  That's a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, you gave me some clues that I need to look at. First, I might have overlooked the hint AF_UNSPEC that I am assigning. I don't know if it can be related to the issue but I definitely need to better understand the impact of this. Also, I will do the tests you suggest about printing byte ordering and document the results when I have them. I don't have printf() support on my embedded platform so I need some time to get back with some valuable results.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thanks for pointing out, bad typo, I will correct

Comment: Thanks all. @MartinR If you want to upgrade your comment as an answer, I would mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POSIX documentation for [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html)
states that

> Upon successful return of *getaddrinfo(),* the location to which res points shall refer to a linked list of **addrinfo** structures, each of which shall specify a socket address and information for use in creating a socket with which to use that socket address. The list shall include at least one **addrinfo** structure. The *ai_next* field of each structure contains a pointer to the next structure on the list, or a null pointer if it is the last structure on the list. Each structure on the list shall include values for use with a call to the *socket()* function, and a socket address for use with the *connect()* function or, if the AI_PASSIVE flag was specified, for use with the *bind()* function. The fields *ai_family*, *ai_socktype*, and *ai_protocol* shall be usable as the arguments to the *socket()* function to create a socket suitable for use with the returned address. The fields *ai_addr* and *ai_addrlen* are usable as the arguments to the *connect()* or *bind()* functions with such a socket, according to the AI_PASSIVE flag.

This implies that – on a POSIX compliant system – IP address and port number in  `ai_addr` are
in *network byteorder,* as expected by the `connect()` function.